# in kendoui.web.2013.2.716 requiring kendo.culture.xx-XX.min.js produces an invalid request for kendo.core.min.js

Tags: kendo-ui

I have just upgraded from kendoui.web.2013.1.514 to kendoui.web.2013.2.716 and have noticed that in the parts of the code where I require (through require.js) a certain kendo.culture.xx-XX.min.js file that also an unsuccessful request for kendo.core.min.js happens and I get an error in the console.

This did not happen with kendoui.web.2013.1.514 and I think this part inside the kendo.culture.xx-XX.min.js files might be to blame:

```
("function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define:function(e,n){return n()})(["../kendo.core.min"]
```

Also this reference to kendo.core appears to only be present in the minified versions. Note that I already have kendo.web.min.js fully loaded and the app works fine even with the invalid request so is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the bundles (i.e. `kendo.web.min.js`) then you shouldn't use RequireJS to load them or any culture files.

I'm sorry that the documentation didn't mention it, I just added a [section to explain this](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-docs/blob/production/getting-started/using-kendo-with/using-kendo-with-requirejs.md#not-for-the-bundles).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. However, this new behaviour completely breaks my project as I am using the kendo.web.min.js bundle which contrary to what the linked docs say, _does not_ include the culture files (except for the US one) so I *am* forced to require them. I think that kendo.web.min.js should either be fixed to contain all cultures or culture files should support loading through require.js (which in fact was not a problem with previous kendo releases).

Comment: @pingo We implemented a solution.  The fix will be present in the next build.  The culture files will no longer require `kendo.core.min.js`.

Comment: So is this fixed in the 2013.2.918 build? The release notes don't mention this issue as far as I can see.